# Let $Y$ ~ $N(-8, 4)$. Compute $P(Y \leq -5)$

Tags: probability

Let $Y$ ~ $N(-8, 4)$. Compute $P(Y \leq -5)$

$\frac{Y+8}{2}$ ~ $N(0, 1)$

$P(Y \leq -5) = \phi(\frac{-5+8}{2}) = \phi(1.5) = 1-\phi(-1.5) = 1-0.668 = 0.332$

The answer is 0.933? Typo or am I wrong?

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh  Oh,I see. Thank you for the point out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your working seems fine, just a minor typo.

$$1-\Phi(-1.5) =1-0.\color{red}0668=0.9332$$